# How to I delete an element of a specific dictionary type in Google Apps Scripts while iterating over it

Tags: dictionary, google-apps-script

How do I delete an entry from this dictionary. The reason I say specific type of dictionary is that there appears to be another dictionary type in Google Apps Scripts. I tried the three commented out functions that I found on other SO questions, but they gave errors.

```
function functionName() {
  d = {};
  d["someString"] = 100;
  d["anotherString"] = 200;
  Logger.log(d);
  //output:  {someString=100.0, anotherString=200.0}

  //??? some function
  //None of these work:
  //d.remove("someString");
  //d.Remove("someString");
  //d.delete("someString");

  Logger.log(d);
  //expected output: {anotherString=200.0}
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT** I realized more specifically what I wanted was to delete the element while iterating over the dictionary with some temporary variable

This ended up working:

```
function functionName() {
  d = {};
  d["someString"] = 100;
  d["anotherString"] = 200;
  Logger.log(d);
  //output:  {someString=100.0, anotherString=200.0}

  for (key in d){
    if (key == "someString"){
    delete d[key];
        }
  }  

  Logger.log(d);
  //output: {anotherString=200.0}
}
```

Comment: If your object isn't frozen or sealed then you should be able to delete it's own properties with `delete Object.propertyname`. [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use code like this to iterate through the dictionary and delete the element d[key]

```
function functionName() {
  d = {};
  d["someString"] = 100;
  d["anotherString"] = 200;
  Logger.log(d);
  //output:  {someString=100.0, anotherString=200.0}

  for (key in d){
    if (key == "someString"){
    delete d[key];
        }
  }  

  Logger.log(d);
  //output: {anotherString=200.0}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any method in an Object itself to delete its own properties (such as Map.prototype.delete()). To do so, one must use the delete operator.` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

```
function functionName() {
  let d = {};
  d["someString"] = 100;
  d["anotherString"] = 200;
  Logger.log(d);
  //[20-03-24 21:02:20:219 MDT] {anotherString=200.0, someString=100.0}
  delete d.someString;
  Logger.log(d)
  //[20-03-24 21:02:20:223 MDT] {anotherString=200.0}
}
```

All you had to do was go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7 and click on builtin objects and lookup it.